# Finding a word and confirming the surrounding letters of a word in a continuous clump of letters efficiently

Tags: python, regex

I'm cutting up `letterlist` at the letters in `cutters`.

The number in `cutspots` means that the letter in `cutters` of the same `position` cuts to the right of that letter, ie 0 would cut to the left.

Following these rules I get results relevant to the words in `wordlist`, saying this generates 1 `'WORD'` and 0 `'ANOTHERK'`s. Although both are in there, they aren't generated by the cutting.

This was originally decently fast, but I found myself, instead of just searching for the words in `wordlist` themselves, needing to confirm that a letter I was cutting up the list by was actually before and after my word in `letterlist`.

This slows down quite a bit by needing to iterate over `cutters` to generate `cutters[position]`, is there any more clever way to figure out if my words in `wordlist` are flanked by the letters in `cutterlist` at the appropriate positions?

```
import re
import itertools

letterlist = ['GIURELABGIRUGHAWUWORDHGUOIHRUANOTHERKHVUHREIAVHRELGBEIUVIREUVBKWORDGOREGK']

cutters = ['K', 'D']
cutspots = [1, 1]

wordlist = [['WORD'], ['ANOTHERK']]

wordfinder = [[sum(x) for x in zip(*[[len(list(set(itertools.chain(*[[m.start() for m in re.finditer(wordlist[i][j], letterlist[h]) if cutspots[position] == 0 and letterlist[h].endswith(wordlist[i][j]) or letterlist[h][m.start()+len(wordlist[i][j])-abs(0-cutspots[position])] is cutters[position]] for position in range(len(cutters))])) & set(itertools.chain(*[[m.start() for m in re.finditer(wordlist[i][j], letterlist[h]) if cutspots[position] == 1 and letterlist[h].startswith(wordlist[i][j]) or letterlist[h][m.start()-cutspots[position]] is cutters[position]] for position in range(len(cutters))])))) for j in range(len(wordlist[i]))] for h in range(len(letterlist))])] for i in range(len(wordlist))]
```

Comment: Why must `wordfinder` be a one-liner? I feel like you'd have a much easier time spreading out your work.

Comment: Also, why is `letterlist` not just a string, and why is `wordlist` a nested list instead of a list of strings like `cutters` is?

Comment: I'm going through very long lists of longer letter-clumps. This was the fastest I could get it to be, so it became easier to keep it this way. I figured I'd ask this in a more complicated way and simplify the question later if no one could answer it. The nesting in wordlist is something I generate beforehand and helps with this process a lot for other reasons.

Comment: "I figured I'd ask this in a more complicated way and simplify the question later if no one could answer it." Do you need help or are testing how others can unravel your 'complicated' qsn?

Comment: Well I do need help but it's an optimization problem first and a string search second, so there's different levels of help I'm trying to get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm willing to bet that the reason your program doesn't work well for large strings is because it has a complexity greater than Θ(n). This function will cut a string how you want it to be cut in that time:

```
def cut_string(string, cutters, cutspots):
    split_list = ['']
    cut_next = False
    for char in string:
        if cut_next:
            split_list.append(char)
            cut_next = (char in cutters) and (cutspots[cutters.index(char)])
        else:
            if char in cutters:
                if cutspots[cutters.index(char)]:
                    cut_next = True
                    split_list[-1] += char
                else:
                    split_list.append(char)
            else:
                 split_list[-1] += char
    return [string for string in split_list if string]
```

Then, we can simply check if any any word in the `wordlist` is a split portion of the string (I'm assuming you meant `wordlist` to be `[['WORD', 'ANOTHERK']]`:

```
def list_cut(letterlist, wordlist, cutters, cutspots):
    out_list = []
    for sub_list, string in zip(wordlist, letterlist):
        cut_list = cut_string(string, cutters, cutspots)
        out_list.append([word in cut_list for word in sub_list])
    return out_list

wordfinder = list_cut(letterlist, wordlist, cutters, cutspots)
print(wordfinder) #[[True, False]]
```